# How to separate Wordpress Blog and Woocommers in different URL but using same Wordpress platform

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am newbie in wordpress and woocommerce.
We have a website that have a Blog page which use wordpress as platform.
URL is something like: www.mysite.com/blog

Now we want to create a woocommerce shop under same wordpress platform. For what I understand the url will look like: www.mysite.com/blog/eShop.

But we want our shop's url looks like this: www.mysite.com/eShop

I assume people already had the solution for this, can any one kindly help?

Our website host on our own server, we installed wordpress on the server as well.

Comment: You can do it with the multisite feature,

https://wordpress.org/support/article/installing-multiple-blogs/

Comment: It is not clear what your existing architecture looks like.  Earid's answer is not necessarily correct.  You may not need a multi-site setup.  We need more information:  Is www.mysite.com a completely different website from www.mysite.com/blog?  A common pattern is for WordPress site to run from the root www.mysite.com, and www.mysite.com/blog goes specifically to the "blog page".  You need to clarify whether www.mysite.com/blog is your blog page or is it the location of your entire wordpress site?